# I am struggling to pass a url variable to be used as a variable for a dynamically generated embed

Tags: javascript

I have previously asked for help and was kindly helped by @tejashwi-kalp-taru by unfortunately still having problems

I want to simply pass the variable of a url ?variable=1234 to an embed script tag to order to be used in dynamic embed based on a variable

I have had help and suggested to create a function which I included but it is still not working

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Parse the URL parameter
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
   name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g,"\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the parameter a variable name



var myvariable = getParameterByName('variable');

$('#myvariable').html(myvariable);

function addScript( src, value ) {
var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
s.setAttribute( 'myvalue', value);
document.body.appendChild( s );
}
<div id="otEmbedContainer" style="width:800px; height:640px"></div>
addScript('https://example.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js? 
embedId=5432&variable=', myvariable);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "still not working" really means, but there is a serious problem in your code.....

You have to be sure to "pop in/out" of the right language when you mix them!

In your example, you aren't properly 'popping' from JS to HTML.....

Here is the same code, corrected and cleaned up a bit (and commented so you can see what I did):

```
<!-- first, do all the HTML (generally, keep it above the JS, though there are times you have to do it differently - but for this example, it should be OK) -->
<div id="otEmbedContainer" style="width:800px; height:640px"></div>

<!-- Now, you will go into JS and do all the JS things-->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // set up your variables first - keeping them together
    // Give the parameter a variable name
    var myvariable = getParameterByName('variable');
    // NOTE: in your example, id of 'myvariable' is not shown, so there may be some issues there????
    $('#myvariable').html(myvariable);

    // Parse the URL parameter
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g,"\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"), results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    function addScript( src, value ) {
        var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
        s.setAttribute( 'src', src );
        s.setAttribute( 'myvalue', value);
        document.body.appendChild( s );
    }
    addScript('https://example.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=5432&variable=', myvariable);
</script>
```

Hope this helps you get this going.  When working with multiple languages, you just have to remember which one you are in and be sure to 'pop' to the other one (when you add PHP into the HTML/JS mix things get complex sometimes, but the same rule applies - be sure you are in the right language by popping in/out and take it a step at a time!

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi CFP support, thank you so much for your help, I did try the code but unfortunately it didnt work, basically I am trying to embed a chat video with Opentok embed and want to create a dynamic room

Comment: you should add that to your tags, then..... - sounds like it may take someone with expertise in Opentok to help you (sorry, I helped on the 'javascript', but 'Opentok' - never heard of it......)